# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__.usersCollection.doc(...).collectionGroup is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have an error as in the description. What did I do wrong? I would like all collection 'hives' documents to be displayed. Is the code that is written in the second photo correct? Or maybe I need to change something? Do I have to add a rule in firebase?

[image]

[image]

index.js

```
import * as fb from '../firebase';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        hives: [],
    },

    mutations: {
        setHives(state, val) {
            state.hives = val;
        },
    },

    actions: {
        async getHives() {
            await fb
                .collectionGroup('hives')
                .get()
                .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                    let hivesArray = [];

                    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        let hive = doc.data();
                        hive.id = doc.id;

                        hivesArray.push(hive);
                    });

                    store.commit('setHives', hivesArray);
                });
        },
    },
});

export default store;
```

Hives.vue

```
<template>
    <ul class="content__list" v-if="hives.length">
        <li class="content__item">
            <p>ID</p>
            <p>Nazwa pasieki</p>
        </li>
        <li class="content__item" v-for="hive in hives" :key="hive.id">
            <p class="content__apiary-name">
                {{ hive.hiveId }}
            </p>
            <p class="content__apiary-name">
                {{ hive.apiary.apiary }}
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    created() {
        this.getHives();
    },

    methods: {
        getHives() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getHives');
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.  Please edit the question to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not allow for collection group queries with `collectionGroup()` to be scoped under a specific document.  `collectionGroup()` can only be used to query across **all** subcollections of the same name in the entire database like this:

```
fb.collectionGroup("hives").get()
```

If you just want to get a specific subcollection nested under a document, just build a reference to it:

```
fb.usersCollection.doc(...).collection("hives").get()
```

Comment: The first way from the collection group does not continue to work with the same error.

Comment: I did `fb.collectionGroup('hives')
                .get()
                .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
                    let hivesArray = [];

                    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                        let hive = doc.data();
                        hive.id = doc.id;

                        hivesArray.push(hive);
                    });

                    store.commit('setHives', hivesArray);
                });`

Comment: What is `fb`?  Please edit the question to show what exactly that is.

Comment: fb is `import * as fb from '../firebase'`

Comment: OK, and what's in there?  I suggest reading this to help you build a complete minimal example were we can see alll the code.  You should **edit your question** to include more details, not leave them in comments.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited Doug, hope helps.